# Static media fails to load in Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

My `settings.py` contains the following configuration parameters.

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/DBMS/DjangoProject/tvshows',
)
```

My project's CSS file is located at `C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/DBMS/DjangoProject/tvshows/static/default.css`.

I have a mock HTML file that should pull in the CSS content, but the URL is a 404.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}static/default.css" />`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

1. `DEBUG = True` in settings.py
2. [**`urls`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

   ```
   from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

   # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

   urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
   ```
3. use [**`context processor`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor) or [**`load static`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) if `{{ STATIC_URL }}` isn't working

   > If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in
   >   your template, you're probably not
   >   using RequestContext when rendering
   >   the template.
   >
   > As a brief refresher, context
   >   processors add variables into the
   >   contexts of every template. However,
   >   context processors require that you
   >   use RequestContext when rendering
   >   templates. This happens automatically
   >   if you're using a generic view, but in
   >   views written by hand you'll need to
   >   explicitally use RequestContext To see
   >   how that works, and to read more
   >   details, check out Subclassing
   >   Context: RequestContext.

Answer (score 3):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}default.css" />`

You need to also edit your [urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development):

Comment: Look at his STATICFILES_DIRS, pretty sure his initial link was correct.